# EF DbContext reverse changes except one column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am using this code to revert changes in a context. My question is how can I revert all changes except for one specific type, where I want to keep one column value as changed.

```
public void RollBack()
{
    var context = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext();
    var changedEntries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();

    foreach (var entry in changedEntries)
    {
        switch(entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;

            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;

            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I have for example entities of type `Student`, `School` etc, and I make changes to different entities and change the property called `Status` on `Student`, and I want to reverse all changes done except I want to save/persist to the database the `Status` value of `Student` entity, how can I do it?

Comment: Using transactions seems more fitting to this problem.

Comment: But transactions will fail everything, I want to still persist the changed done to Status field from Student entity but revert all other changes.

Comment: If you have a unit-of-work/transcation you would .savechanges() at the end of the transaction and all would save or none would save. If you want to ensure part of that is saved then you would call saveChanges on just that entity outside and before you commit all the other changes together.

Comment: Roll back and recommit your student. whats the use case here?

Comment: I have 1000 entities in my context where their status is changed...